# Having trouble with bootstrap's nesting logic?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I'm having a little trouble aligning my columns in bootstrap the way I like. This is what I'm looking for: [image: column example]

I've been fooling around with this, and I've been able to get A and B aligned okay, but E is usually too far down on the page. C, D, and F all align perfectly, but I'm having trouble nesting B & E properly. Either B is aligned with A, and E will align with C/D, and F will render on the page below E, on the left side of the page.

Comment: Do add html and css so it will help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your application with bootstrap div classes:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavender;">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavenderblush;height:100px">A</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:green;height:50px">C</div>
         <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;height:50px">D</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:black;height:50px">F</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:blue;height:50px">B</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:pink;height:150px">E</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

But First you have to use **bootstrap.min.css,bootstrap.min.js,jquery.min.js** files in your application.

Answer (score 1):

See example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akaggkju/)

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-9">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 box a">
A
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 box">
C
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 box">
D
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 box">
F
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 box">
B
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 box e">
E
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Took me a second to understand it, but I've got it now. Thanks very much. One problem I was having was that I was using margins in the CSS which was causing them to stack vertically.